# Unpredictable Touch Events With Talkback Enabled

Tags: android, accessibility, touch-event, talkback

I am developing an Android app which supports Talkback and Explore By Touch but have run into issues when responding to two fingered scrolling with a custom view.

As I understand it, holding two fingers on the screen and moving them around should generate the same sequence of touch events at the custom views onTouchEvent method as using a single finger with Talkback/Explore By Touch switched off.

I'm expecting to see an ACTION_DOWN event when the user touches the screen with two fingers, followed by a series of ACTION_MOVE events and finally an ACTION_UP event when they stop touching the screen.

This happens sometimes, but quite often, upon placing two fingers on the screen I receive a volley of events which are difficult to interpret correctly.

In order to discount as much code as possible, I've written a simple sample app which is just a basic Android app created with the ADT wizard featuring a single custom view declared as follows;

```
package com.example.accesseventtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class AccessTestView extends View {

    public AccessTestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        int action_type = event.getActionMasked();

        if (action_type != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            Log.d("onTouchEvent", event.toString());

        return true;
    }
}
```

The custom view is intended to consume all touch events that are passed through and returns true to indicate this, it also copies all events to the debug log except for ACTION_MOVE to reduce the amount of debug log produced. It is instantiated by the following layout;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.accesseventtest.MainActivity" >

    <com.example.accesseventtest.AccessTestView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Running this with Talkback and Explore By Touch enabled, then placing two fingers on the screen, sometimes emits a single ACTION_DOWN event to the debug log, like so;

> 10-06 14:21:41.356: D/onTouchEvent(30151): MotionEvent {
>   action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=1, x[0]=828.0, y[0]=744.0,
>   toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0,
>   edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=23426762,
>   downTime=23426762, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }

which would be ideal, however it sometimes emits this sequence;

> 10-06 14:32:53.026: D/onTouchEvent(30151): MotionEvent {
>   action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=1, x[0]=926.0, y[0]=607.0,
>   toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0,
>   edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=24098432,
>   downTime=24098444, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
>
> 10-06 14:32:53.031: D/onTouchEvent(30151): MotionEvent {
>   action=ACTION_CANCEL, id[0]=1, x[0]=1054.0, y[0]=801.0,
>   toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0,
>   edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=24098449,
>   downTime=24098444, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
>
> 10-06 14:32:53.036: D/onTouchEvent(30151): MotionEvent {
>   action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=1, x[0]=926.0, y[0]=608.0,
>   toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0,
>   edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=24098444,
>   downTime=24098444, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }

which is also not a problem as I can filter out the first DOWN action on receipt of the CANCEL one. Where problems arise is when it emits a large sequence of events such as this;

> 10-06 14:20:47.681: D/onTouchEvent(30151): MotionEvent {
>   action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=1, x[0]=697.0, y[0]=933.0,
>   toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0,
>   edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=23373092,
>   downTime=23373092, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
>
> 10-06 14:20:47.731: D/onTouchEvent(30151): MotionEvent {
>   action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=1, x[0]=697.0, y[0]=936.5,
>   toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0,
>   edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=23373137,
>   downTime=23373092, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
>
> 10-06 14:20:47.731: D/onTouchEvent(30151): MotionEvent {
>   action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=954.0, y[0]=643.0,
>   toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0,
>   edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=23373137,
>   downTime=23373137, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
>
> 10-06 14:20:47.736: D/onTouchEvent(30151): MotionEvent {
>   action=ACTION_POINTER_DOWN(1), id[0]=0, x[0]=954.0, y[0]=643.0,
>   toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, id[1]=1, x[1]=696.0, y[1]=937.0,
>   toolType[1]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0,
>   edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=2, historySize=0, eventTime=23373137,
>   downTime=23373137, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }

The initial DOWN,UP,DOWN sequence confuses the higher level code and gets interpreted as a click event.

Could anyone who has successfully implemented a custom view that supports two fingered scrolling with Talkback/Explore By Touch enabled shed any light on where I'm going wrong with this?